# Display posts and thumbnails with certain tags

Tags: tags

I want to display specific posts from an array with specific tags i.e. "Bolivia" and "Brazil" and then show the post thumbnail and permalink.

This is the code I am using so far but as you can see I am not calling the tags.

Thanks.

```
<?php query_posts(array('category__in' => array(4), 'posts_per_page' => 4)); ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

              <?php $currentid = get_the_id(); ?>

              <div class="list-box">

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($currentid, array(120, 100)); ?></a>

                 <div class="list-box-title"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></div>

               </div>

              <?php
           endwhile;
       endif;

  wp_reset_query();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [WP docs for query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Relevant excerpt:

```
The following returns all posts that belong to category 1 and are tagged "apples"

    query_posts( 'cat=1&tag=apples' );

You can search for several tags using +

    query_posts( 'cat=1&tag=apples+apples' );
```

Or using the array version you're using, something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'category__in' => array(4),
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tag' => array('Bolivia', 'Brazil')
)
query_posts($args);
```

String version for your case:

```
query_posts('category__in=4&posts_per_page=4&tag=Bolivia,Brazil');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I cannot get it to work. I am using this code:

      <?php $args = array(
       'category__in' => array(4),
      'posts_per_page' => 4,
       'tag' => array('Bolivia', 'Brazil')
        )

        ?>

       <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

       <div class="list-box">
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($args, array(120, 100)); ?></a>

     <div class="list-box-title"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></div>

  </div>

  <?php
     endwhile;
     endif;

        wp_reset_query();
    ?>

     ?>

Comment: What's the error? Also have you tried the string version?